# Remove "strange" padding - bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I have created a row with the following code:

```
<div class="row justify-content-between row-spacing">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 bg-orange" >
     <h1>Word1<br>Word 2<br>Word 3</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 bg-orange">
     <p class="content-text ">Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which has the blow appearance:

[Website screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L960Z.png)

My question is: How can I make Padding#1 and Padding#2 to have the same value?

Even after having used margin/padding - top:0 I did not solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide a snippet with html and css or a fiddle?

Comment: Fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/b0padmca/)

Comment: i'm guessing the padding is the same, but the <h1> has a margin-top that is related to the font size

Comment: The fiddle provided is different from the image on this question, and I can't see that difference showed. But i'm thinking the same as the above comment from @Dirk

Comment: well yes thanks for the fiddle, its not the margin top, but is releated to the lineheight of the font itsself